# Does anyone have experienced cross browser issues with "encodeURIComponent(string)"

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I need to make URL from some custom string values dynamically. I have doubt on  [`encodeURIComponent(string)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)  function whether it has cross browser issues does anyone experienced trouble with this function (I am not using any JS libraries)?

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/when-are-you-supposed-to-use-escape-instead-of-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`encodeURIComponent` works as advertised in a cross-browser fashion.  Use it in preference to `escape`.

Comment: *"Use it in preference to `escape`."* Er, yes, since `escape` doesn't do URI-encoding at all. It does something similar, but different.

Comment: There's no reason I can think of to ever use `escape` (it's just misdesigned) - but it's similar enough to be confusing, hence the warning.

Answer (score 6):

Go for it. This is exactly what [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) is for and it's well-supported across browsers. I've never heard of a serious issue with it on any major implementation.